# Static value of date not working in type="date" in html?

Tags: html, input

I have a input tag like this:

```
<input class="span2" type="date" name="date" value="01/12/2012">
```

The input form in template is displayed like mm/dd/yyyy. The static value that I provided is not working. However when I change the type to date it works. Does html not allow this?

Comment: What are you trying to show?

Answer (score 7):

The `input` tag with `type="date"` is supposed to accept dates in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD` and not `mm/dd/yyyy` as you are trying to pass.

Read more about it on [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html) and validity is defined as per [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339).

---

Therefore, the value should be passed as

```
value="2012-01-12"
```

Comment: Damn, beat me by 10 seconds!

Answer (score 3):

You're not conforming the HTML5 specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#input-author-notes

The specification requires that all literal date values be written in ISO 8601 format: `yyyy-MM-dd`:

> The format used "on the wire", i.e. in HTML markup and in form submissions, is intended to be computer-readable and consistent irrespective of the user's locale. Dates, for instance, are always written in the format "YYYY-MM-DD", as in "2003-02-01". Users are not expected to ever see this format.